# Convert string to perfect number

Tags: algorithm

Given a string, we need to find the largest square which can be obtained by replace its characters by digits (leading zeros are not allowed) where same characters always map to the same digits and different characters always map to different digits. If no solution, return -1.

Consider the string "ab" If we replace character a with 8 and b with 1, we get 81, which is a square.

How to find it for given string ? It is given that string length can be at max 11.

Please help me find a suitable and efficient way

Comment: With max 12 chars it should be fast enough with brute force. Maybe not very elegant, but effective.

Comment: @Burkhard Brute force in what way ?

Comment: Example with "ab": iterate over a = 0..9 and b=0..9. Check if a*10+b is valid. If so, save the value and continue. The largest found number is the solution.

Comment: @Burkhard so do it for all alphabets from a to z ?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @ChrisMaes I had tried what Burkhard had said, but its time complexity is very huge !!

Comment: @mat7 can you edit your question and add that code? It is hard to help if you do not show a little effort...

Comment: @mat7.: tell us the limits..that means length of the string..give the source of the question if necessary

Comment: @Burkhard added my code . Please check now

Comment: The last digit can only be 0 1 4 5 6 or 9

Comment: @mat7 thanks. I have no time right know to answer. Jusanne's editted answer seems good. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry can't comment, not enough reputation for it so I'll answer here.

@mat7 about what you said in your question comments, no you don't have to do it for every letter from a to z. You only have to do it for the letters present in your string (so at max 12 letters, not 26).
The first thing I would even check is how much different letter you have, if it's 11 or 12 different letters you can directly return -1 since you can't have different letters having the same number.

Now, supposing the input string being "fdsadrtas", you take a new array with only each different letter => "fdsadrt"
And with this array you try all possibilities (exclude the obvious mismatching options, if you set 'f' to 4 and 'd' to 5, 's' can only be 12367890 (and f can never be 0)), this way you will exclude lots of possibilities, having as worst case 10! instead of 12^10. (actually 9*9! with the test of the first one never beeing 0 but it's close enough)

EDIT 2 : +1 samgak nice idea !
The last digit can only be 0,1,4,5,6,9 so the worst number of tests drop even to 9*6*8!

10! is by far small enough to be brute tested, keep the higher square value you found and you are done.

EDIT :

Actually It would work (in a finite reasonable amount of time) but it is the wrong approach now that I have thought about it.

You will use less time in looking all the squares numbers that could be a solution for your string, using the exemple I gave above it's a string of length 9, and checking each square who is length 9 if he could be successfully mapped into the string.

For a string of length 12 (the worst case) you will have to check the square values of 316'228 to 999'999, who is way less than the >2 millions check of the previous proposition. The other proposition might become faster if you start accepting long strings but with only 12 you are faster this way.

Comment: I had done that . Check my solution . Are there more optimisations ?

Comment: Well I haven't touched c++ for a while so I'm not completely sure your code is actually doing what I proposed (but I'm not sure he doesn't neither). Maybe if it's taking to much time you could try it the other way around => you check all the square numbers that can fit in your string, and check if they could be mapped with your rules (that should be ways faster now that I think of it, never more than a few dozen checks)